# How to save frames with cv2.imwrite from multiple videos in different folders?

Tags: python, opencv

Okay so I searched a lot on the internet and I came across various methods to extract frames out of videos, but none of them seemed to work for multiple videos. So I came up with my own solution to it. But the status as of now is that I am able to extract frames out of one video and save it in a folder by its name. But the code is not working for the second video. Following is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\hp\Videos\multi.py", line 21, in <module>
    cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(location , "frame%d.jpg"  % counter), frame)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgcodecs\src\loadsave.cpp:715: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_img.empty() in function 'cv::imwrite'
```

Here is my full code

```
import os 
import cv2 

def createFolder(directory):
    try:
        if not os.path.exists(directory):
            os.makedirs(directory)
    except OSError:
        print ('Error: Creating directory. ' +  directory)

listing = os.listdir('C:/Users/hp/Videos/TwoVideos')
counter = 0
for vid in listing:
    createFolder('./data/'+vid)
    vedeo = "C:/Users/hp/Videos/TwoVideos/"+vid
    ret = 1
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(vedeo)
    while ret: 
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        location = './data/'+vid
        cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(location , "frame%d.jpg"  % counter), frame)
        # cv2.imwrite("frame%d.jpg" % counter, frame) 
        counter = counter + 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check for `ret` AFTER, not BEFORE you capture the frame:

```
while ret: 
    ret, frame = cap.read()
```

Should be:

```
while True: 
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret : break
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, you're trying to overwrite some existing frames.

Try to assign a video ID while saving the frame to keep the names unique.

```
import os 
import cv2 

def createFolder(directory):
    try:
        if not os.path.exists(directory):
            os.makedirs(directory)
    except OSError:
        print ('Error: Creating directory. ' +  directory)

listing = os.listdir('C:/Users/hp/Videos/TwoVideos')
counter = 0
video_id = 2
for vid in listing:
    createFolder('./data/'+vid)
    vedeo = "C:/Users/hp/Videos/TwoVideos/"+vid
    ret = 1
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(vedeo)
    while ret: 
        try:
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            location = './data/'+vid
            cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(location, f"vid_{video_id}_frame{counter}.jpg"), frame) 
            counter = counter + 1
        except Exception as e:
            print('Error')
            print(e)
```

Comment: Your code outputs only a single frame. Its definitely creating a new folder a second video. So that's progress. But kindly look into it